# R RefClass inherit from list

Tags: r

Following situation:
If I define a RefClass in R and using the standard `list` as Superclass like this:

```
A <- setRefClass(
  Class = "A",
  contains = "list",
  fields = c(
    a = "numeric"
  )
)
# works fine at first 
aObj <- A()
str(aObj)
aObj[[1]] <- "a1"
aObj[[2]] <- "a2"
length(aObj)
unlist(aObj)
```

everithing works fine at first, but the show methods throws error

```
> aObj <- A()
> aObj
> Error in { : could not find function "{"
> aObj[[1]] <- "a1"
> aObj
> Error in list2env(new("A", .Data = list("a1"), .xData = <environment>),  : 
names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x
```

I have no clue for the first error and for the second
I unsuccessfuly tried to fix it with the following:

```
setMethod("names", signature = ".A", definition = function(x){
  paste("A",1:base::length(x), sep="")
})
```

Is there a way to get the above working properly?
I know it's probably not wise to inherit from a standard class, but what are the alternatives to implement a custom list class without reimplementing the common list functionality?

Comment: i still have no clue how to adress this problem.  Am I doing something so strange that nobody has or had a similar problem in R?!?! As I already mentioned in the question, I don't need exectly a sollution for the code above. A hint on how to implement a "custom" list without reimplementing common list functionality would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Given your stated intentions, I don't think reference classes are what you are looking for here. Reference classes can be very effective for many use cases, but if your goal is to preserve a list-like interface to your new class, i.e. it can access generic functions as if it were a list, you should look elsewhere.

Any reference class object you create is a special type of environment. This means for a start that standard list subsetting like `aObj[[1]]` just won't work. The only reason that your example allows you to do this is because your definition of `A` is broken and doesn't actually return a proper reference class object:

```
A <- setRefClass(
  Class = "A",
  contains = "list",
  fields = c(
    a = "numeric"
  )
)

aObj <- A()
is.environment(aObj)
#> [1] FALSE
```

The reason why it is broken is that a reference class can only inherit from another reference class, or from an S4 class.

Now, you *could* implement a reference class where the main data member is a list and shares some list functionality like this:

```r
A <- setRefClass(
  Class = "A",
  fields = c(a = "list"),
  methods = list(
      
    show = function() {
            cat("A special list of type A containing:\n");
            methods::show(.self$a)
    },
    append = function(x) {.self$a <- base::append(.self$a, x); return(.self)}
  )
)

# Functions to convert back and forwards between A and normal list
as.list.A <- function(x) x$a
as.A      <- function(x) A(a = as.list(x))


aObj <- A()
aObj
#> A special list of type A containing:
#> list()

aObj$append(1:3)
#> A special list of type A containing:
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 3
```

But this doesn't solve your problem of wanting to be able to access by subsetting, or inheriting the useful characteristics of a list. So what can you do?

I think in terms of functionality you are looking for an S3 class. Perhaps an implementation something like this, where we just define a simple object constructor and a few generics:

```r
A <- function(a = numeric()) structure(list(a = a), class = c("A", "list"))

as.list.A <- function(x) {class(x) <- "list"; x;}

str.A <- function(x) cat("A magical list of wonders called", 
                         deparse(substitute(x)), "\n")

print.A <- function(x) {
  cat("A special list of type A containing:\n")
  print(as.list(x))
}
```

Which behaves like this:

```
aObj <- A(a = 1:3)

aObj
#> A special list of type A containing:
#> $a
#> [1] 1 2 3

aObj[[1]] <- 1:4
aObj[[2]] <- 2:5

aObj
#> A special list of type A containing:
#> $a
#> [1] 1 2 3 4
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 2 3 4 5
  
str(aObj)
#> A magical list of wonders called aObj
```

Because `aObj` effectively inherits from list, any generic functions that you have not declared will use the generic methods as if it were a normal list. That allows you to do things like:

```
lapply(aObj, mean)
#> $a
#> [1] 2.5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 3.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks for your answer. I already was thinking of using a S3 class for this purpose, but it feels like I would break my clean all RefClass architecture. The problem with S3 classes in my point of view is, more or less non of the OOP paradigma is implemented in it. Anyhow, it seems there is just no propper way of implementing list like Ref classes.